# IndexeDB not working for chrome packaged app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, indexeddb

IndexeDB works fine when used for a normal chrome extension . But when the same chrome extension is transformed into a chrome packaged app . indexeDB gives the following error 
This happens when the data is added to the objectstores(tables).

```
Uncaught DataError: Evaluating the object store's key path yielded a value that is not a valid key
```

Comment: What is the `console.log`ged value of the key?

Comment: You are correct . My data source is not giving proper values . thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Cross check whether your data source is proper or not . The above error happens when data to be entered does not have proper keypath value